# inline a image that is stored as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an image that is stored in a string. Instead of taking the time to save it as a file I am trying to display the image inlined.

send_data() does not fit my needs as the method is considered to be a render so the rest of the page will not display.

Is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps?

```
  #Assuming x holds your image as a string, and is a PNG image
  str = ""
  str << "<script>document.write('<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"
  str << escape_javascript(Base64.encode64(x))
  str << "\">');</script>"
  raw str
```